# How do I make a grouped bar chart that shows proportions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dummy dataset `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Product = c(755, 728, 417, 355, 913, 634, 385, 208, 204, 696, 968, 816, 279, 869, 823, 646, 986, 674, 806, 335, 731, 734, 107, 105, 512, 859, 159, 113, 353, 105, 205, 919, 243, 717, 838, 408, 423, 357, 408, 464, 724, 643, 943, 648, 623, 451, 449, 135, 842, 711),
    Category = c("Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese"),
    Sub_Category = c("White", "Camembert", "White", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Brown", "Wholemeal", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Brown", "White", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "Brie", "Brie", "White", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Gouda", "White", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "White", "Camembert", "Brie", "Brie", "Camembert", "Brie", "Camembert", "Gouda", "Camembert", "Wholemeal", "White", "Camembert"),
    Fibre = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

With this data, I want to create a grouped bar chart that plots the proportions of products containing fibre by sub-category and grouped by category.

I can create a simple plot that shows the proportions of products containing fibre by category:

```
library(tidyverse)

proportions <- df %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(Proportion = mean(Fibre == TRUE) * 100)

ggplot(proportions, aes(x = Proportion, y = reorder(Category, Proportion), fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")
```

But what I would really like to show is a plot with six bars representing the proportions of products containing fibre for each of the sub-categories (not the main categories) and grouped together (by colour/legend) by the main category.

**How can I create a grouped bar chart showing this in R?**

Comment: In your use `fill = Sub_Category` inside aesthetic and also use `position = 'dodge'` inside `geom_bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(
  Product = c(755, 728, 417, 355, 913, 634, 385, 208, 204, 696, 968, 816, 279, 869, 823, 646, 986, 674, 806, 335, 731, 734, 107, 105, 512, 859, 159, 113, 353, 105, 205, 919, 243, 717, 838, 408, 423, 357, 408, 464, 724, 643, 943, 648, 623, 451, 449, 135, 842, 711),
  Category = c("Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese"),
  Sub_Category = c("White", "Camembert", "White", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Brown", "Wholemeal", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Brown", "White", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "Brie", "Brie", "White", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Gouda", "White", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "White", "Camembert", "Brie", "Brie", "Camembert", "Brie", "Camembert", "Gouda", "Camembert", "Wholemeal", "White", "Camembert"),
  Fibre = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

proportions <- df %>%
  group_by(Category, Sub_Category) %>%
  summarise(Proportion = mean(Fibre == TRUE) * 100)


ggplot(data = proportions, aes(x = Category, y = Proportion, 
                               fill = Sub_Category)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat_summary` which will directly compute the proportion as needed

```
ggplot(df, aes(Category, as.numeric(Fibre), fill= Sub_Category))+ 
   stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'bar', position = 'dodge') + 
   ylab('Fibre')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding an R base approach to demonstrate the powerful capabilities of `table()` and `barplot()`:

```r
Y = with(df, prop.table(table(Sub_Category, Category)))
barplot(Y, beside = TRUE, main = "Your grouped bar chart",
        xlab = "Category", ylab = "Fibre (%)",
        col = rainbow(length(rownames(Y))),
        args.legend = list(x = "topright", inset = c(-.02, 0)),
        legend.text = rownames(Y), space = c(.1, 2))
```

[image]